# What are alternatives to Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, bootloader

For windows multiboot, I find Windows Boot Manager is quite restricitve, even more so after GPT-UEFI booting that it doesn't even show my ubuntu partition and EasyBCD says UEFI settings of windows is preventing it to give such options.

it is not just removing metro interface, that I have removed long ago, even removing that just changes its look and doesn't change its working.

What are alternatives for me that I can use in place of default Windows Boot Manager?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/

Comment: I am primarily windows learner person, I have heard that grub is *nix thing. My ubuntu installation is still on grub and shows my windows installations though doesn't boot them. If it can be used for windows and can totally replace windows boot manager, I would sure like to use it. But more information will be required to get myself started. Thanks.

Comment: @Mawg Why "upvote" button is not visible to me next to your comment?

Comment: Well, you can certainly use Grub for "Windows only". Alas, I am very busy with meetings to day, which is why I only posted a comment, rather than an answer. I hope that you can figure it out from the documentation. You probably can’t upvote yet because you don’t have enough reputation on this, but thank you for thinking of it :-) Good luck!

Comment: Take a look at [How to install GRUB from inside Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/381285/how-to-install-grub-from-inside-windows-7) and [Install Grub2 on USB and HDD from Windows](https://www.aioboot.com/en/install-grub2-from-windows/)